micropython pyb module not found
I want to debounce a button in micropython and found this page on the micropython docs: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/tutorial/debounce.html
It uses a library called pyb but my problem is that when I try to import it I get an error that the module doesn't exist. I assumed it was an external module but it's not showing up in pypi.
I am using the latest version firmware version for micropython for the raspberry pico (1.23.0)

If you look closely at the homepage it says "MicroPython tutorial for the pyboard". pyb is a system module of the pyboard, it's not available on a Raspberry Pi.
